# How to implement this method that downloads image from URL in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-image

I'm using this method to download image

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String u, int width, int height) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(u);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }     
    }
```

This method and bitmap are used in Adapter to show image for every list item:

```
Bitmap bitmap = PickanteHelper.getBitmapFromURL(image_url, 150, 150);
holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

In order to avoid NetworkOnMainThread exception I suppose I should use AsyncTask while loading each image?

Comment: well you could use threads and communicate back to the ui using holder.itemImage as the view check my previous answers ive answered questions about these..

Comment: Don't know what it is, I suppose it's lib like Picasso? Problem is that I need to recalculate inSampleSize of image before setting it in list item so that list scrolling wouldn't lag

Comment: are you referring to me?

Comment: Nope, there was a comment but guy deleted it

Comment: i think you should need to use Volley or Picasso libary to download image to get rid of managing yourself. also the image download faster.

Comment: these library also provide you callback on image download.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
// initilize the default HTTP client object
final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

//forming a HttoGet request 
final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
    //check 200 OK for success
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + 
                " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
        return null;
    }

    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            // getting contents from the stream 
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
    getRequest.abort();
    Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
            " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
} 
return null;
}
```